# What does the question mark on availability group replica mean in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, ssms

I'm doing some testing with availability group in SQL Server. When I'm on the primary replica, I can see all replica nodes have a refresh icon on them.

[image]

But when I check on a secondary replica, all other nodes have a question mark on their replica names. What does it mean?

[image]

Btw, I'm using SSMS 18 with SQL Server 2022.

Comment: It typically indicates that the availability state of those replicas is currently unknown or cannot be determined.
Can you check the status/state of the replicas? 
To get the actual availability state of the replicas, you can right-click on each replica, select "Properties," and navigate to the "Availability" tab. The availability state will be displayed there, providing more detailed information about the synchronization status of the replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each secondary replica connects to the primary, and so the instance hosting the primary node knows the state of all the replicas.

The secondary replicas don't communicate directly with each other.